# TapeEquilibrium: Single failed test case... where is the error?

Tags: c#

TLDR: Codility ["Challenge"](https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/tape_equilibrium/) - [my results](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoSZUTSC-GGB/): Where is the error?

Short Description ([Full Description](http://i.gyazo.com/c928bbdb24e58548c1a64193c83025da.png)): Given an Array, split the array into two (Upper and lower parts) and give the minimum difference between two possible parts in absolute value.

My thought process is:

1. create an "Upper" and "Lower" bucket for sums.
2. In one pass of the array, we get a sum for the "Upper" bucket.
3. Then, one array value at a time, move the numbers into lower (Upper-n, Lower+n).
4. At each step, get the difference (Abs(Upper-lower))
5. Monitor lowest "Minimum"

Submitted Code:

```
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        // Quick results:
        if (A == null) return -1;
        if (A.Length == 0) return -1; // Can't split
        if (A.Length == 1) return -1; // Can't split
        if (A.Length == 2) return Math.Abs(A[0] - A[1]); // Only one way to split

        // Hold above/below/result...
        long lower = 0;
        long upper = 0;
        var min = long.MaxValue;

        // Pass#1: Sum All to get "Upper"
        for (long i = 0; i < A.Length; i++) upper += A[i];

        // Pass#2: 
        // foreach in array
        // ... Shift number from upper to lower
        // ... Calculate new difference/minimum
        for (var i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            lower += A[i];
            upper -= A[i];

            var diff = Math.Abs(upper - lower);
            min = Math.Min(min, diff);
            if (diff == 0) return 0;
        }

        return (int) min;
    }
```

Out of 13 test cases, the only one that Codility fails me on is: "Small Numbers". it says "Wrong answer, expected 20 got 0". It doesn't show the test data it uses, so I'm left guessing as to "Why".

Where is my error? I think I've stared at it too much, but I can't seem to figure out what case would "break" my function.

Edit: Fixed translation. Submitted code to Codility uses a Foreach, and the code I have here is a For. Corrected the variables in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't take into account one of the rules: `0 < P < N`.
 Your second loop is assuming `0 < P <= N`.

Assume this input:

```
10, 10, -20
```

Your code would return 0 but 40 would be correct.

Fix:

Change your second loop header to

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
```

[Proof](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoGM7S8F-VC6/)

Comment: Someone else put an answer up (That's now missing?) that mentioned the `0 < N < P` requirement - where as my answer (without the `-1`) is `0 < N <= P`. That definitely fixes the issue :) Looks like the `foreach` loop was wrong in multiple ways. Thank you.

Comment: @WernerCD: No, there was no other answer like this. With my reputation, I can even see deleted answers, so I know for sure that I was the only one answering this question. I did however, edit my initially very short answer to contain an explanation, the fix and the proof.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Expected answer is 20 not 40. 10-(-10) = 20; 20-(-20) = 40. Minimum is 20.